# How to create universal Splashscreen in android

Tags: android

I am creating an android application in sdk2.1. i have put 3 different images in three type of drawable folders to support different resolution, also to support different screen sizes i have to create different layouts eg layout-small, layout-large etc. If I use fill_parent then my splash screen looks blurred in some case thats why i have used wrap_content. How to create universal Splashscreen in android which will work in all types of resolution and also in all types of screen size.

### MyApp.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class MyApp extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }

}
```

**splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/spash_screen_image">
</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sunil.spinner"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MyApp" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different drawable folder and put there images of different resolution but the name will be the same

Create XML like the following

**splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/spash_screen_image"
    >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/spash_screen_image"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

drawable-hdpi, -mdpi and -ldpi do not translate to resolution. They translate to high, medium and low dots-per-inch, or pixel density. Check your DPI and use images accordingly.

The layout / GUI editor is your best friend. Try changing to various screen sizes there and see which images are picked up for each configuration. You can generate separate layout files for specific configurations from there.